# Formatting CSV Data for chart.js: How to Create a JavaScript Data Structure from CSV File

Tags: javascript, csv, chart.js

I have a CSV file named `data.csv` with the following content:

`data.csv`:

```
time,voltage
0.0,20
0.2,1
0.3,15
0.4,2
0.5,31
0.6,11
```

I want to create a JavaScript data structure from this CSV data and store it in a variable. The desired data structure should look like this:

**Desired Data Structure**:

```
[
 { x: 0.0, y: 20 },
 { x: 0.2, y: 1 },
 { x: 0.3, y: 15 },
 { x: 0.4, y: 2 },
 { x: 0.5, y: 31 },
 { x: 0.6, y: 11 }
]
```

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

---

I specifically need this data structure for creating a chart using the `chart.js` library. If anyone has experience or examples with parsing CSV data into a suitable format for `chart.js`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    <script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
        const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        yAxisID: 'yA',
                        label: 'Temperature',
                        data: [
                            { x: 0.05, y: 12 },
                            { x: 0.15, y: 19 },
                            { x: 0.25, y: 3 },
                            { x: 0.35, y: 5 },
                            { x: 0.45, y: 2 },
                            { x: 0.55, y: 3 },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        yAxisID: 'yB',
                        label: 'Voltage',
                        data: [
                            { x: 0.0, y: 20 },
                            { x: 0.2, y: 1 },
                            { x: 0.3, y: 15 },
                            { x: 0.4, y: 2 },
                            { x: 0.5, y: 31 },
                            { x: 0.6, y: 11 },
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    yA: {
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'left',
                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'blue' },
                        grid: { display: false },
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        //backgroundColor: 'blue',
                        borderColor: 'blue',
                        tension: 0,
                    },
                    yB: {
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'left',
                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'green' },
                        grid: { display: false },
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        //backgroundColor: 'green',
                        borderColor: 'green',
                        tension: 0,
                    },
                    x: {
                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true },
                        type: 'linear',
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you  want to create / transfor the data? on the server or the client side?

Comment: hello, my data.csv is in the same folder as my index.html is. so very simple in the <script> tag i would use the data

Comment: Did my question, solve your question, or did I miss something? If it did solve your question, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to load the data with the `fetch` command, and when it is loaded simply use string and array functions to construct the json, something like this:

```js
function renderChar(csv){
  let textLines = csv.split(/\r?\n/).slice(1); // -> remove the header

  // -> this crete the json object
  let jsonData = textLines.map( line => {
    let [x,y] = line.split(',').map( x => parseFloat(x));
    return { x, y}
  })

  console.log(jsonData); 
  // -> Here you would create the Chart
}

// -> load the data.txt
fetch('data.txt').then( res => res.text()).then( renderChar );
```

> *Nevertheless if you could prepare the json data on the server and not on the client, this would increase performance an load times.*